# Time strings subtraction

Tags: c++, adtf

The code after reading .dat file and generates .csv format file which is consist of  many frame names (columns) and respective timings (microseconds)(rows) stored in a string separated by ';' :

`MFK3_ECAN 1625069169;1625072194;1625072216;1625072229;1625072241;1625072253;` `MFK3_VIDEO_FrameID 1625334304;1625612508;1625890712;1626168916;1626447120;1626725324;`
What I need help with is to find a solution, by which these above mentioned two "specific name" strings can be subtracted for each time frame (converted to sec i.e. micsec/10^7) with a constraint that if there is a time difference of 3 or more seconds one state should be logged as ".dat file is corrupt".

Part of code reading .dat file:

```
    std::string file_name = m_Filename.toStdString();
    size_t found = file_name.find (".dat");
    file_name.erase (found, 4);
    file_name.insert (found, "_Timestamp_Log");
    file_name += ".csv";
    m_log.open (file_name.c_str(), std::ofstream::out);
    QList<tTimeStamp> tmp_lst;
    for (int col = 0; col < m_nStreamCnt; col++)
    {
        tmp_lst = m_TimestampMap.value(col+1);

        m_log << m_StreamIDMap.value(col+1).toStdString() << ";"; //writing Column names

        for(int row = 0; row < tmp_lst.size(); row++)
        {
            m_log << QString::number(tmp_lst.at(row)).toStdString() << ";"; //writing Row values
        }

        m_log << endl;
    }

    m_log.close();
```

Comment: I dont understand your algorithmic problem. Can you please add an example of an corrupted and valid file, reduced to the essential parts?
Your code listing is no help either. Please add some comments, what you are doing, and what is working/not working.

Comment: Sure, I can try to explain it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, finally I worked out with the solution. As per now its clear I wasn't asking with complete information. But nevertheless hopefully the solution would help others who might come across such issue.
Problem 1: I had to look for a specific stream name and than store it via toFloat() for later subtraction. Caution: toInt() or toStdString() would give incorrect values.

Problem 2: QString::number(tmp_lst[0]) would give the first number from string to subtract and check either difference is less than 3 seconds.

```
for (int col = 0; col < m_nStreamCnt; col++) //m_nStreamCnt contains function names 
    {
        tmp_lst = m_TimestampMap.value(col+1);

        m_log << m_StreamIDMap.value(col+1).toStdString() << ";"; //Column names

        if (m_StreamIDMap.value(col+1) == "MFK3_VIDEO_FrameID")
        {

                    m_log << QString::number(tmp_lst[0]).toStdString() << ";";  //Row values
                    m_current = QString::number(tmp_lst[0]).toFloat();
            m_current = m_current/10000000;
        }

        else if (m_StreamIDMap.value(col+1) == "MFK3_ECAN")
        {
            m_future = QString::number(tmp_lst[0]).toFloat(); //
            m_future = m_future/10000000;
                    m_log << QString::number(tmp_lst[0]).toStdString() << ";";  //Row values
        }  
m_diff = std::abs(m_current - m_future); //

    if (m_diff <= 3)
    { //details etc}
```

Comment: glad to see you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what you want from your description. Maybe following trivial code helps?

```
long pre = -1;
for(int row = 0; row < tmp_lst.size(); row++)
{
     //writing Row values
     if (pre == -1 || ((long)tmp_lst.at(row) - pre) < 3000000) {
         m_log << QString::number(tmp_lst.at(row)).toStdString() << ";"; 
     } else {
         m_log << ".dat file is corrup";
     }
     pre = tmp_lst.at(row);
}
```